# Excluding specific values from a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Hi there, i have a table in a database and i only want to exclude values where AccType In ('Lisa') And AccCodeValue In ('1a','4g','1c')
return everything else.

**So the expected result set is**

[image]

**but the actual result set gotten is**

[image]

what is wrong, i thought it would be a simple query like

```
   Select * From table Where AccType In ('Lisa') And AccCodeval Not In ('1a','1c','4g')
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What have you tried? Any google search will answer this for you, without having to post here like its a new question...

Comment: @seanLange if the answer was in my comment, i don't think i will be asking the question.

Comment: @nahaelem Is expected result correct? Looks like wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT *
FROM [yourtable] AS a
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM [yourtable] AS b
     WHERE
       a.accid = b.accid
       AND
       a.acctype = 'lisa'
       AND
       a.accCodeValue IN('1a', '4g', '1c'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but something like this is what I think you're looking for:

```
select * from [yourTable]
where  AccType <> 'Lisa' 
and  AccCodeValue not in ('1a', '4g', '1c')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Acc
WHERE AccType <> 'Lisa' AND AccCode NOT IN ('1a','4g','1c')
```